# Javascript Fetch ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when deployed to Kubernetes

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, kubernetes

I developed a simple NodeJS express app with an endpoint giving static response, using JavaScript to `fetch` and display the message on an HTML Page. It works when I test/run it on the local machine.

When deployed to Kubernetes and accessing the UI using a `Node_Public_IP:Node_Port` NodePort Service , it gives,

```
GET http://localhost:3000/live net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
TypeError: Failed to fetch
at window.onload (app-controller.js:6:5)
```

I have tried `http://0.0.0.0:3000/live` and `http://127.0.0.1:3000/live` as well with same error. What should I be changing?

When I try `http://<name-of-kubernetes-service>:3000/live` it gives `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Code is as follows,

NodeJS Code

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();
 
app.use(cors())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));

app.get('/',   async (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/', 'index.html'));
});


app.get('/live', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send({
        "status": "OK, it is working!!!"
        });
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("App running on port - 3000");
})

module.exports = app;
```

```js
console.log('We are inside client.js');

/* on page load  */
window.onload = function() {

    fetch("http://localhost:3000/live", {
            method: "GET"
        })
        .then(function(res) {
            if (res.ok) {
                return res.json();
            }
            thrownewError('Request failed');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function(data) {
            document.getElementById('appStatus').innerHTML = ` ${data.status} `
        });
};
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <div class="middle">
            <h1>Application Status</h2>
            <h3 id="appStatus">**app status placeholder**</h3>
         </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript"  src="app-controller.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

-- edit --
Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.17

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json /usr/app/

RUN npm install

COPY . .
    
EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: The error means that the client is not able to establish a connection to the server. What is your dockerfile setup, did you expose the port 3000?

Comment: Yes, i have exposed the port in Dockerfile. Updated the question with Dockerfile

Comment: Can you confirm whether the browser from which you are trying access the application and the kubernetes cluster where your application got deployed are on the same machine, also can you check your cluster IP or deployment IP and try to access this application using them.

Comment: Kubernetes server is running on the cloud and I can access other apps deployed on it using any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got the solution from another post. Javascript runs on the Browser and hence cannot reach localhost endpoints running on the Kubernetes server.

We need to use Ingress/K8S Node Public Endpoint.